# Error on Flutter with the URL_Launcher package

Tags: android, ios, flutter, asynchronous, dart

Since yesterday, when I use a GestureDetector with the url_launcher package I'm getting this error:

````
E/flutter (17573): #0      _musicAreaState._launchURL (package:GiramosApp/ui/views/home_screen/widgets/music_area.dart:37:7)
E/flutter (17573): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17573): #1      _musicAreaState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:GiramosApp/ui/views/home_screen/widgets/music_area.dart:55:13)
E/flutter (17573): #2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (17573): #3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
E/flutter (17573): #4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (17573): #5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:259:7)
E/flutter (17573): #6      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
E/flutter (17573): #7      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
E/flutter (17573): #8      GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter (17573): #9      RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:263:11)
E/flutter (17573): #10     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:157:7)
E/flutter (17573): #11     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:103:7)
E/flutter (17573): #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:87:7)
E/flutter (17573): #13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (17573): #14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (17573): #15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (17573): #16     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (17573): #17     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
E/flutter (17573): ```

Any thoughts?
````

Comment: This does not look like the whole error report. Is there some more info before your current first line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the error, I don't know why but it works deleting the async function. So, the result it's:

```
launchUrl(url) {
   launch(url);
 }
```

On iOS it works with the async flavour, but not on Android.

Answer (score 2):

From API30 (Android 11) onwards, your Android app has to list all apps it interacts with.

Add this in your android manifest file (android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Install the package properly using the steps given [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/). You should add a dependency of [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/) in pubspec.yaml file. If you have done that,

To solve this issue you should clean the project using `flutter clean`, and then you upgrade your flutter using `flutter upgrade`. This will solve the problem for sure. If not, you create a new project and then paste the code in it.